# Auto position Jquery Popup

Tags: jquery

```
<html> 
 <head>
   <script src="../../../js/jqueryv1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {       
      $('.wings').click(function(event) 
      {
        $(this).next('.popupbox').fadeIn("slow");
        $('body').css('background','#333');
        //$("body").css({ "background":"#333", "opacity":"0.4","filter":"alpha(opacity=40)" });
      });

       $('.popupclose').click(function(event) 
       {            
           unloadPopupBox();
           $('body').css('background','white');
       });     

       function unloadPopupBox() 
       {
          $('.popupbox').fadeOut("normal");       
       }  
       $(".popupbox").hide();
    });
   </script>
   <style>
    .container {font-family:verdana; font-size:13px; margin:0px auto; width:1200px; }
    .popupbox { position:center; background:#FFFFFF;  z-index:100px; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px lightgray; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px lightgray; 
                box-shadow:0 0 5px lightgray; display:none; min-width:100%; min-height:100%; overflow:auto;}    
    .popupclose { border:0px solid lightgray; color:#6FA5E2; line-height:15px; float:right; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none; }
   </style>
 </head>

 <body> 

  <div class="container">

    <!-- popup1-->
     <a class="wings" style="background:#8AC007;color:#FFF;font-weight:bold;">Popup1</a>
     <div class="popupbox"><div style="height:30px;"><img class="popupclose" src="../../../images/close.png" style="float:right;"></img></div>  
     <img src="train.jpg"/>     
     </div>
    <!-- popup1-->    

    <!-- popup2-->
    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
      <input type="button" class="wings" value="Popup2"/>
      <div class="popupbox">
      <div style="height:30px;"><img class="popupclose" src="../../../images/close.png" style="float:right;"></img></div>
       <table>
        <tr><td>USERNAME : </td><td><input type="text" size="30%"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>PASSWORD : </td><td><input type="password" size="30%"></td></tr>      
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="LOGIN"></td></tr>
       </table> 
    </div>  
    <!-- popup2-->  

    <!-- popup3-->
    <div style="margin-top:10px;">      
      <p class="wings">click on the image to view big screen</div>    
      <div class="popupbox"><div style="height:30px;"><img class="popupclose" src="../../../images/close.png" style="float:right;"></img></div>       
      <div><img class="wings" src="god.jpg"/></div>
    </div>  
    <!-- popup3-->
   </div><!--container-->

 </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3ac9Z

I have three popups to show on a same page.

(1) when I click any of the above three, the popup should display at the center of the 
    browser automatically and the position, width(auto), height(auto) should be similar for all the popups and it should not differ.

(2) I need to adjust the opacity of my background where it shouldn't allow to operate at the back end until I close the popup, but right now I could see some of the div borders, images, buttons at the background when I open popup .

I need something like this : http://www.joomdle.com/en/forum/r09-support/10576-moodle-joomdle-joomla(discussion4)

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Starting fiddle added.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option: `position: center` :)

Change your css like:

```
.popupbox { 
  position:absolute; 
  width: 200px; /* Or what you want */
  height: 200px; /* Or what you want */
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px; /* This should be  - width / 2 */
  margin-top: -100px; /* This should be  - height / 2 */
  background:#FFFFFF;  
  z-index:100;  // z-index is not pixels ;)
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; 
  box-shadow:0 0 5px #999; 
  display:none;  
  overflow:auto;
}
```

And if you want some kind of overlay.. you should do another div like:

```
#overlay {

 position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  z-index: 90; /* just smaller than popupbox */
}
```

Comment: That seems to have issues. The popups are partially offscreen to the left. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3ac9Z/7/

Comment: Could anyone suggest me